# Error in code to find the factorial of a number entered by a user

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, factorial

```java
public static int Factorial(int num) {
    int factorial = 1;
    int num = Integer.parseInt(txtFactorial.getText());

    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        factorial = factorial * 1;
    }

    return factorial;
}
```

The code above is a code I'm trying to put in a subroutine to find the factorial of a number entered by a user and display it in a `JLabel`. The problem is that it is showing an error with the `int num = Integer.parseInt(txtFactorial.getText());` code. This piece of code gets the entry of the user and stores it into the variable num for it to be later used to find the factorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your calculation.

```
public static int Factorial(int num)
{
    int factorial = 1;
    // delete this line int num = Integer.parseInt(txtFactorial.getText());    
    for (int i = 1; i<=num; i++)
    {
        factorial = factorial * i;
    }    
    return factorial;
}
```

And use the function like this:

`ResultLabel.setText(string.valueOf(Factorial(Integer.parseInt(txtFactorial.getText()))));`

Answer (score 0):

**Variable 'num' is already defined in the scope**

```
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(txtFactorial.getText());
```

Write the above f you want a new variable

```
num = Integer.parseInt(txtFactorial.getText());
```

Write the above if you want to change the value of the existing variable num.

Answer (score 0):

There is a duplicate in the variable `num`, you need to use another value for this local variable:

```java
int num = Integer.parseInt(txtFactorial.getText());
```

use this Instead:

```java
int parsedNum = Integer.parseInt(txtFactorial.getText());
```

if you change the name of the local variable, then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The factorial of a *positive integer* `n` - is the product of all positive integers less than or equal to `n`. The factorial of `0` is `1`.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(factorial(3));   // 6
    System.out.println(factorial(0));   // 1
    System.out.println(factorial(-10)); // 1
}
```

```java
public static int factorial(int num) {
    // factorial of a positive integer, or 1 otherwise
    int factorial = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        // sequential multiplication
        // of numbers in the loop
        factorial = factorial * i;
    }
    return factorial;
}
```

---

Using *streams*, your code might look like this:

```java
public static int factorial(int num) {
    // factorial of a positive integer, or 1 otherwise
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, num)
            // sequential multiplication
            // of numbers in the stream
            .reduce((a, b) -> a * b)
            .orElse(1);
}
```